# reading # char in python

Tags: python, utf-8, nlp, stanford-nlp

can someone help with me reading "#" char in python? i can't seem to get the file. because this is an output from the stanford postagger, is there any scripts available to convert the stanford postagger http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml file to cwb. http://cogsci.uni-osnabrueck.de/~korpora/ws/CWBdoc/CWB_Encoding_Tutorial/node3.html

so this is the utf-8 txt file that i'm trying to read:

```
 如果#CS 您#PN 在#P 新加坡#NR 只#AD 能#VV 前往#VV 一#CD 间#M 俱乐部#NN ，#PU 祖卡#NN 酒吧#NN 必然#AD 是#VC 您#PN 的#DEG 不二#JJ 选择#NN 。#PU
    作为#P 或许#AD 是#VC 新加坡#NR 唯一#JJ 一#CD 家#M 国际#NN 知名#VA 的#DEC 夜店#NN ，#PU 祖卡#NN 既#CC 是#VC 一#CD 个#M 公共#JJ 机构#NN ，#PU
```

So with this code i'm not readin the # char in the utf-8 txt files:

```
#!/usr/bin/python # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

'''
stanford POS tagger to CWB format
'''

import codecs
import nltk
import os, sys, re, glob

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

cwd = './path/to/file.txt' #os.getcwd()

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(cwd, 'zouk.txt')):
        print infile
        (PATH, FILENAME) = os.path.split(infile)
        reader = codecs.open(infile, 'r', 'utf-8')
        for line in reader:
                for word in line:
                        if word == '\#':
                                print 'hex is here'
```

Comment: What happens when you run this?

Comment: Do you mean for your code to work character by character?

Comment: i got no output other than the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if word == '\#':
```

This probably doesn't do what you think it does.  (Hint: `print "\#"`)

Comment: print '\#' gave me \# instead of #

Comment: exactly. so you're not comparing against `#`, you're comparing against `\#`. But there are no `\#` in your input string...

Comment: thank you thank you!! any idea how do i skip to the next word if i read a "#" char? the continue code in if - else would work right?

Answer (score 1):

If Python does not recognize an escape sequence then it will include the backslash in the string.

```
>>> '\#' == '\\#'
True
```